# Correct way to edit pg_hba.conf

Tags: bash, postgresql, installation

So, I am attempting to create an install script for my application (targeting Ubuntu 16).  It has to create a postgresql user, grant permission to that user to authenticate via password, and grant permission to that user to authenticate locally.  I only want to grant permission to do that on one database, the application database.  So I need to insert the line `local databasename username md5` above the lines that reject unknown connections, e.g., in the "Put your actual configuration here" section of `pg_hba.conf.`  (`pg_hba.conf` uses position in the file to determine priority:  first rule encountered that matches the connection gives the final result.)

To add this line, my script runs:

```
sudo awk '
/# Put your actual configuration here/ {
    print "local databasename username md5"
}
{ print }
' /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf

# other setup

service postgresql restart
```

But that's less than optimal.  First, the version number will change in the future, so hardcoding the directory is poor.  Second, that's making a comment in someone else's project an actual structural part of the config file, which is a horrible idea from all possible points of view in all possible universes.

So my question is twopart.  First, **is there a good, correct, and accepted method to edit pg_hba.conf** that I can use in an installation script instead of kitbashing about with text editors?

Second, if there is no good answer to the first part: **is there a programmatic way to ask postgresql where it's pulling pg_hba from?**

Comment: not sure if you want the debian/ubuntu way or not.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a programmatic way to ask postgresql where it's pulling pg_hba from?

```
show hba_file;
-- or
select current_setting('hba_file');
```

Comment: May not be the best idea for a script, one pg_hba file can be used by a lot of databases. With this method, you'll have to know what databases to connect to and what port/hosts to use.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - A user usually knows what database he's using or is going to install. Or should at least.

Answer (score 3):

## Debian tool chain

> So my question is twopart. First, is there a good, correct, and accepted method to edit pg_hba.conf that I can use in an installation script instead of kitbashing about with text editors?

Yes, however, you'll probably find it unsatisfactory.

Upstream, PostgreSQL doesn't support multiple versions and installs with their build tools. Debian does. So Debian has invented a concept of a `cluster` which is essentially a name and a version number.

Building a tool on Ubuntu or Debian, you should also probably use a name and version number.

> Second, if there is no good answer to the first part: is there a programmatic way to ask postgresql where it's pulling pg_hba from?

Yes, there is a tool called `pg_conftool`. The default cluster's name is `main`. If you want the 9.5/main cluster. You can do this..

```
pg_conftool -s 9.5 main show hba_file
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

You can see conftool can make use of a version and name, but strictly it may not require one.

```
/usr/bin/pg_conftool [options] [<version> <cluster name>] [<configfile>] <command>
```

If you want to know more about a *cluster* in this context, check out check out all the binaries starting with `pg_*` but first and foremost `pg_ctl` and `pg_ctlcluster` (the debian wrapper)

Comment: Requesting a clarification of the first part of your answer.  'Debian cluster' is a phrase that googles poorly (and StackOverflows poorly) because of the more common usage of 'cluster' to refer to massively parallel computing, and `man cluster` refers to a specific Postgre command.

Comment: @sgfit Check out all the binaries with `pg_*` but first and foremost `pg_ctl` and `pg_ctlcluster` (the debian wrapper)